# Is it possible to set duration of push notification in react native ios?

Tags: react-native

I am using custom sound for push notification in react native ios.
Is it possible to adjust the duration of push notification in ios?

Since the custom sound is not a completely different sound, it consists of 3 repeat sound, 5 repeat sound, and 7 repeat sound.
The problem is that the toast and sound appear only about the length of the 3 repeat sound and disappear after that.

I am using `@react-native-community/push-notification-ios` and
I saw the *repeat* option, but I think it's different, so I'm thinking about how to do it.

Is it possible with the `Notifee` library?

If anyone has a solution, please advise to me.

Answer (score 0):

I found that Apple's iOS has a time to display the Notification Toast by default, and when that time is exceeded, the Toast disappears and the custom sound stops as well.
In other words, if it is a custom sound that is less than approximately 5 seconds, it can be confirmed that it is played as desired.